# Как преобразовать список в класс?

Tags: c#, классы, list

Есть класс

```
public class DB 
{
    string name{get;set;};
    string surname{get;set;};
    string phone{get;set;};
}
```

Есть список `list` в котором след. данные

```
["Сергей"]
["Иванов"]
["44-444"]
["Петр"]
["Петров"]
["55-555"]
["Сидр"]
["Сидоров"]
["66-666"]
```

Как этот список `list` трансформировать в `List<DB>`?  Есть вариант использовать счетчик и через цикл foreach проверять if (index%2=0) then это Name

Comment: Все верно, а в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как более элегантно это сделать) через лямба например

Comment: как определяете элегантность? обычный for скорее всего самым элегантным способом будет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый просто способ использовать цикл `for`, примерно так

```
for(var i=0;i<list.Count;i+=3){
    listDB.Add(new DB(){
        name = list[i],
        surname = list[i+1],
        phone = list[i+2]
    })
}
```

Если принципиально использование linq

```
var listDB = (from ss in list.Select((e, i) => new { e, i })
              group ss.e by ss.i / 3 into g

              select new DB()
              {
                  name = g.First(),
                  surname = g.Skip(1).First(),
                  phone = g.Last()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Первый сниппет покатит для `IList<>`, но не для `IEnumerable<>`. Хотя можно материализовать заранее.

Comment: @VladD, слова _Есть список list_ из поста намекнули мне, что это все-таки `List<string>` :-D

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего применить метод [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) из пакета MoreLinq:

```
list.Batch(3, triple => 
        {
            var parts = triple.ToList();
            return new DB()
            {
                name = parts[0],
                surname = parts[1],
                phone = parts[2]
            };
        })
```

Comment: а этот пакет поддерживается еще?:)

Comment: @Grundy: Джон Скит вроде говорит, что да.

Comment: там кстати интересно, если ровно не делится, то в последней группе упадет, странно что он просто не вернул с элементами по дефолту, я про вот эту строчку: `yield return resultSelector(bucket.Take(count));`

Comment: @Grundy: Упадёт по идее мой код, но не MoreLinq: Take просто вернёт меньше элементов.

Comment: ну да, просто я бы подумал, что мы должны гарантированно иметь количество элементов которое указали :)

Comment: @Grundy: в принципе, можно добавить проверку после `.ToList()`, но мне не хотелось утяжелять код.

Comment: не, это больше к автору библиотеки вопрос :-) скорее всего расчет на то, чтобы не менять никаким образом исходную коллекцию. сколько дали, столько и получили

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, идея Джона Скита понятна: нельзя «изобретать» новые объекты, иначе нет способа отличить искусственно созданные объекты от реально находящихся в списке.

Comment: @VladD _"метод Batch из пакета MoreLinq"_ -- есть метод Buffer в System.Reactive.Linq.Observable, System.Reactive.dll

Comment: @Stack: Мне не очень нравится идея с Rx в данном контексте. С теоретической стороны, это смешения push- и pull-семантик, что не очень хорошо. А с практической как следствие, теряется ленивость, список читается весь даже если это не требуется клиенту.

Answer (score 0):

Если строк в файле очень много, и в конце файла возможно, что не хватает одной или двух строк, то можно использовать Observable.Buffer

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\test.txt").ToObservable();
var dbs = Observable.Buffer(lines, 3).Select(g => CreateDB(g));
foreach (var db in dbs.ToEnumerable()) {
   Console.WriteLine(db.name + " " + db.surname + " " + db.phone);
}

// десериализация DB из строк 
static DB CreateDB(IList<string> values) {
  var o = new DB();
  var props = typeof(DB).GetProperties();
  for(var i=0; i < values.Count; i++)
     props[i].SetValue(o, values[i].Trim('[', ']', '"'));
  return o;
}

public class DB {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string surname { get; set; }
  public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой и элегантный способ на чистом Linq в одно действие.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(list.Count / 3) - 1)
          .Select(i => i * 3)
          .Select(i => new DB
                       {
                          name    = list.ElementAt(i),
                          surname = list.ElementAt(i + 1),
                          phone   = list.ElementAt(i + 2)
                       });
```

В реальном коде, конечно, стоит ещё проверить количество элементов в  `list` на 0 и кратность 3, но для простоты можно оставить и так.